# What are the pitfalls when implementing a web page like app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, web-services, webforms

I'm planning to implement some app that performs similar functions as some website does. An app should be able to post, get and view some data. Most viewing data is available only after login. Payments. The webservices are .NET asmx XML services.

So, I'm planning to use UIKit, drag and drop some text fiels. For posting the data, I will do some manual input validation, assemble input into a string, post it to the server. Also, some parsing will be done after getting info form a webserver. Now, I haven't done any website app before, so I'm just curious what are the potencial problems that I might run into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are asking about potential technical issues. The ones I faced recently working on an app of this type and workarounds are:

1. Maintaining your session with the server if you are combining native UI screens together with UIWebView's of your website.
2. XML Parsing can be hairy at times, so JSON is the best option depending on your preference. The other solution is to output XML in the PLIST format which is easier to code against. On the server side PHP has some PLIST generating libraries. Am not aware of what is available on .NET.
3. On the iOS side the ASIHTTP library helps make it easier to post to websites, particularly when you are using binaries etc.
4. Depending on your use case you may also consider a pure web based UI version which resides inside a UI webview. If you are planning on going this route JQueryMobile is a pretty good solution for rendering iOS like UIs. This saves you quite a lot of effort on the communicating with the webservice and parsing etc.

Thats all I can think of for now.

Comment: I would like to add that you do not need to work with frameworks like phone gap. For camera and other functionality you can write native code. By adjusting the size of the UIWebview on the view where you need camera, geo-location or even audio recording you can easily have the best of both native and web worlds without resorting to frameworks such as phone gap.

Answer (score 1):

Biggest problem might be getting it approved by Apple if they think it should be just a website and not an app. They might cite: "Limited Functionality". see :  https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html

I can also reccomend www.sudzc.com

Answer (score 0):

- Your UI will certainly not be as responsive as a native app.
- Your users won't be able to use your app without an Internet connection/flaky connection
- You'll have to rebuild all native controllers yourself if you wan't your app to look like a native iPhone app.
- You'll have to rely on libraries like PhoneGap to use most of the hardware/non HTML supported functions (like geolocation, camera, etc.)

Etc.